# Pyarrow Not Working on Python 3.8 ModuleNotFoundError AttributeError

Tags: python, conda, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I've used pip to install pyarrow for python 3.8 on Mac and Linux and am getting errors like:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow.gandiva'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow.csv'
AttributeError: module 'pyarrow.fs' has no attribute 'S3FileSystem'
```

I've also tried the conda forge installation which resolves the
`AttributeError: module 'pyarrow.fs' has no attribute 'S3FileSystem'` problem but creates other errors. What do I do here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issues you are seeing on macOS python3.8 with `pyarrow=0.17.1` - I suspect this might be a problem with conda pulling in an older version.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For 3.8 the conda installation seems to work fine on macos. The pip version, however, doesn't and on Linux 3.8 Conda doesn't work. I believe arrow has been compiled with different flags on conda and on pip and on different platforms so not all optional libraries are supported everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like both the pip and conda forge installations are not complete for Python 3.8. I've tried the pip installation for 3.7 on Linux and this seems to be working fine.

Answer (score -1):

please check here https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/5987. This has provided the solution.

Comment: Can you explain in detail as only giving link is not sufficient?
You must always explain the links.